# Sagemaker not using GPU even though it is deployed in GPU instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I was able to successfully deploy my object detection model into **Sagemaker** and get predictions from it but turns out the **GPU** is not being utilized when prediction are to be done.

I deployed my custom model using the code:

```py
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge')
```

Then, I get predictions by:

```
results = predictor.predict(imageData)
```

This process takes around ~15+ seconds and when I check the utilization graph in endpoint dashboard I get it as:

[image]

The GPU memory is being used but no peaks under utilizations. Can anyone guide me on what's happening here?

**Some more info:**

- Image used: 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tensorflow-inference:1.14-gpu
- Instance used: ml.p2.xlarge

> Let me know if I need to provide some more info.

Comment: Maybe your model is not as complex as you think and the GPU is bored.

Comment: @Joe Hi. It is a faster-rcnn model from detection zoo by tensorflow (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md). This should be taking GPU, as object detection is pretty common scenario where real time detection is like a must. Also, how do I know at what point my model takes GPU?

Comment: 1) Is the prediction successful?
2) The first prediction is slower as the model is loaded on demand. Are additional predictions slow?
3) Have you checked the log of the endpoint? Anything unusual?

Comment: @JulienSimon Hi, thank you for the reply. 1: Yes the prediction are successful. 2) The first prediction takes around ~28seconds and yes preceeding prediction are slow ~15 seconds. 3) Yes I have checked the endpoint logs and there is nothing unusual. Any guesses on what happened?